# Spring Boot with Hibernate: Auto-generating database schema with columns which can holds fractions of seconds

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring-boot project where I need to save the last modified time of entities with microseconds accuracy - actually, an audit property where entity version is kept. In my development environment, I use a MySQL database and MySQL's temporal types support fractions up to 6 digits. So I can define the respective column with `timestamp(6)` or `datetime(6)` when the schema is manually created.

But I want the schema to be auto-generated with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` property. I know it's not a good practice in a production environment, but this project is going to be a template or seed for many other projects. So I need to keep it in generic form so that it does not depend on the underline database system.

For MySQL, I can get it to work using `columnDefinition` argument of `@Column` annotation like below.

```
@Version
@Column(columnDefinition= "datetime(6)")
Timestamp version;
```

But this won't work in other databases where `datetime(6)` is not a valid temporal type.

I tried auto-generating the particular database schema setting `scale` (`@Column(scale= 6)`) argument, but it just neglects the fraction part generates a column of type `datetime`, not `datetime(6)`.

I'm curious if there is a way to do that, though I'm not aware.

Can you guys give me some input on this?

## Update

@crizzis in his comment taught me that it is a matter of using correct **hibernate.dialect**. So, with **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect** I was able to auto-generate **datetime(6)** columns. Then I tried to control the number of digits in fraction part with `scale` argument without no success, it always have 6 digits.

Now I'd like to know if it is possible without using `columnDefinition` argument inside `@Column` annotation.

Comment: Why not just let Hibernate do its job? A `TIMESTAMP` SQL type is already mapped by Hibernate to a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column definition (see `org.hibernate.MySql57Dialect`). For most other databases, it will degrade gracefully to a simple `TIMESTAMP`. If you want to switch to another database in the future which also supports microsecond precision, look up the relevant `Dialect`; it will likely include support for the feature, and if not, you can always customize it

Comment: @crizzis Yes, I got it now. It's a matter of **hibernate.dialect** we use.  With **MySQL5InnoDBDialect** I got just **datetime** columns without fraction part. Now with **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect** I get **datetime(6)**. But is there a way to limit the number of digits in the fractions part.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySql57Dialect` (and/or `MySql57InnoDbDialect`, depending on the version of Hibernate), the `TIMESTAMP` SQL type is already mapped to a `TIMESTAMP(6)` database column type:

```
registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime(6)" );
```

This means the default column definition should support microsecond precision. The best course of action is to let Hibernate generate the schema without overriding the column definition. For most other databases, it will degrade gracefully to a simple `TIMESTAMP`.

If you want to switch to another database in the future which also supports microsecond precision, look up the relevant `Dialect`; it will likely include support for the feature, and if not, you can always customize it.

> Then I tried to control the number of digits in fraction part with scale argument without no success, it always have 6 digits.

This is because in the `registerColumnType` call above, the precision of the `TIMESTAMP` is fixed at 6. If you want to be able to customize it, roll out your own custom dialect (extending from `MySql57Dialect`) and override the definition with:

```
registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, 6, "timestamp($l)"); //l for length, p for precicion, s for scale
```

You will then be able to override the column length using either `length`, `precision`, or `scale` (depending on what you put inside the brackets). Note that the second argument to the method defines the maximum possible column length for this particular datatype, so if you want e.g. nanosecond precision, you should change it to 9.